How to statically build [apache htpasswd] as statically linked binary
I try to statically build htpasswd but failed
I don't know how to ./configure properly, I tried lots of args about "static" but still failed

--enable-mods-static=all

--enable-static-support

--enable-static-htpasswd

--with-included-apr


./buildconf

./configure --prefix="$BUILD_DIR" --enable-static-support --enable-static-htpasswd
# ./configure --prefix="$BUILD_DIR" --enable-mods-static=all --enable-static-support --enable-static-htpasswd --with-included-apr --enable-modules=all
# ./configure --prefix="$BUILD_DIR" --enable-static-support --enable-static-htpasswd --with-included-apr
# ./configure --prefix="$BUILD_DIR" --enable-static-support --enable-static-htpasswd --with-included-apr --enable-mods-static=all
# ./configure --prefix="$BUILD_DIR" --with-included-apr --enable-mods-static=all --enable-static-support --enable-static-htpasswd --enable-static-htdigest --enable-static-rotatelogs --enable-static-logresolve --enable-static-htdbm --enable-static-ab --enable-static-checkgid --enable-static-htcacheclean --enable-static-httxt2dbm --enable-static-fcgistarter --enable-jansson-staticlib-deps --enable-curl-staticlib-deps
# ./configure --prefix="$BUILD_DIR" --enable-static-support --enable-static-htpasswd --with-included-apr --enable-mods-static=reallyall --enable-modules=reallyall --enable-ssl-staticlib-deps

make clean
./config.nice
make -j "$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_CONF)"
make install

if command -v file >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  file "$BUILD_DIR/bin/htpasswd" | grep --color=always -E 'statically|dynamically'
fi

https://github.com/apache/httpd/archive/refs/tags/2.4.59.tar.gz
https://dlcdn.apache.org//apr/apr-1.7.4.tar.gz
https://dlcdn.apache.org//apr/apr-util-1.6.3.tar.gz
